# Variable height sticky footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to create a variable-height sticky footer and have got close but I'm falling at the final hurdle.

I've used the method shown here: http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/ and it seems to work fine in IE but in Chrome I end up with the following result.

[image]

Whereas it should look like this (IE):

[image]

Notice that in Chrome the elements seem centered vertically in some strange way but in IE, the header is at the top, the footer is at the bottom and the content element in the middle is filling the rest of the space.

Has anyone had this problem before?

This is essentially my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body id="frm">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="divHeader" class="row">
            <div>
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Menu</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="divAll" class="row expand">
            <p>test>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="divFooter" class="row">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
html {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
body {display:table;width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
.row {display:table-row;height:1px;}
.row.expand {height:auto;}
```

I know there is a way to do this with display:flex but I need to support IE9+ so this is not an option.

I also know that you can do it with a fixed height footer and then change the height with media queries but this is also not an option as the content of the footer can vary and thus the height can vary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: [Your example](http://jsbin.com/vowuw/1/edit) works fine in IE8+, Firefox, Chrome and Safari (safari needs the height of `.row.expand` to be changed to `100%` like [this](http://jsbin.com/vowuw/2/edit))...